# CSS Slide Up / Down transition of multiple divs. Issues with placing them on same position (replace position)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

If you look at this fiddle you will understand exactly what the problem is.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8U9RS/5/)

Issues :

1) I cannot get the second `div` to replace the position of the first `div` when clicking "Salgsapparat". It stacks below.

2) How should I use the translate (minus) offset to make sure that the other div's are invisible at first ?

3) Do I have to "initiate" the div's like this first ? `$('#kunderContainer').addClass('closed')` It seems unnecessary, but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

So somthing like [this jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8U9RS/6/)? You can just add the class `opened` to the slide you want to show first and remove the class and add it to the next slide onclick. Also `position:absolute;` makes the elements not get pushed down. You don't need a `closed` class for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this :) Solves a part of my problem atleast!

Comment: Ah :( It seems i cannot use position:absolute... This is due to using Susy Container CSS. I have to do the same without the position:absolute.

Comment: So would somthing like [this work](http://jsfiddle.net/8U9RS/7/) then? Manipulating the height instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do can be easily accomplished by adding the following css line:

**display:none !important;**

You'll want to add this line when the slider is closed.

Unless there's a particular reason you're trying to offset items to make them hidden?

```
  .slider.opened {
  /* visible */
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0%);
  transform: translate(0, 0%);
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: yeah.. but it should be displayed when it's opened, and invisible when .closed. I had some issues with display:none, since the transition effect didn't work when using display:none.